# Use vim keybindings in visual studio code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to use vim keybindings in the terminal in Visual Studio Code? As far as I know, the vscodevim extension does not change anything for the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

What I use to deal with this on Windows 10:

1. Get the **Windows Terminal** in the Microsoft Store page
2. Install **WSL**, any distro flavor you like
3. Install **Zsh** shell in the WSL

   - edit the *.zshrc* file adding the line **bindkey -v** to enable vi mode (the lines that start with # are comments by the way)
   - optional: install *Oh My Zsh* framework to style the WSL terminal and see the vim modes more easily (though i prefer to keep it more minimalist and simple)
   - you can check if it's working by pressing the *ESC* button in the terminal and trying to move up/down with the classic *j* or *k* buttons
4. In **VS Code**, assumming you already have the Vim extension enable just set the WSL as the default terminal

   - open the terminal with *ctrl + ñ*
   - clic in the '+' button in the right corner and chose 'Select Default Profile' and chose the WSL terminal
   - once there try to use the ESC and the j or k to move through the commands already typed and *ENTER*
   - to change to the code editor again, press *ctrl + tab* to avoid using the mouse (ctrl + ñ to select the terminal and so on)

I hope my advice will help you. Good luck.